# How can I import my Google Chrome history to Firefox?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, export, import

I'm trying to import my Google Chrome browser history into Firefox. It doesn't seem to be working. I've tried the import option while selecting only cookies and history (deselected bookmarks) but even after going through all the steps, it still doesn't import the chrome history.

Comment: Bookmarks are easy, but why browsing history, that's a new... I don't think this is possible using standard tools. Settings has an option to clear the browsing history (or certain parts of it), but I haven't seen anything to export. 3rd party tools may be available for this. Google is your friend. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically you can export your Chrome history using the following GitHub repository: https://github.com/christiangenco/chrome-export-history This apparently allows for export to `.CSV` (personally preffered) or `.JSON`

Also, this repo has been made into a Chrome extension. However, I don't know the limitations of the "try it now" feature. In any case, it's on GitHub, so it's Open Sourced. If you're planning on using it this one time, no biggie. If you find it useful the proper etiquette is to donate. It's only $3 after all.

Anyways, after you export Chrome `.CSV` you can use FireFox Add-On [Flem](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flem/) to import .CSV's. It doesn't specifically mention Favorites but it "technically" should work.

I've never personally used this method so I'm uncertain but I'm familiar with programatically accessing .CSV's (just a simple list) so this at least conceptually works. If not these specific tools in tandem, then others exist that will work, I'm sure. If it doesn't work, comment back and I'll do what I can.